# How do I find weighted combinations of different lenght arrays equal to x?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two arrays (a and b) of different length. I also have a set of weights and I need to find the weighted combinations of a + b that equals x. The sum of the weights must always equal 1.

I have tried the following:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(1.2, 1.7, 0.1)
b = np.arange(0.0, 0.9, 0.1)
x = 0.6
weights = np.arange(0.05, 1.05, 0.05)

a.resize(b.shape)

lw = []
for w in weights:
    for y in weights:
        np.where((w * a + y * b) == x, lw.append(w), np.nan)
```

This gives me a list of 20*20 weights, i.e. all the weights.

I need a list with weights where: w * a + y * b = x

Any idea how I can do this?

Comment: Do : `np.argwhere(np.isclose((weights[:,None,None]*a) + (weights[:,None]*b), x))` and use the first two columns for ID-ing the weights and the last col to ID the corresponding elem from `a` and `b`.

Comment: @Divakar I forgot to specify that the sum of weights must always equal 1. Added to the question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC here's one approach -

```
sums = weights[:,None, None, None] * a[:,None] + weights[:,None,None]*b
idx = np.argwhere(np.isclose(sums,x))
out_idx = idx[np.isclose(weights[idx[:,0]] + weights[idx[:,1]], 1)]
```

Here, the first two columns are the combinations of indices of `weights` and the last two columns are indices for `a` and `b` respectively.

Verify for given sample -

```
In [165]: sums = weights[:,None, None, None] * a[:,None] + weights[:,None,None]*b

In [166]: idx = np.argwhere(np.isclose(sums,x))

In [167]: out_idx = idx[np.isclose(weights[idx[:,0]] + weights[idx[:,1]], 1)]

In [168]: out_idx
Out[168]: 
array([[ 1, 17,  3,  5],
       [ 3, 15,  2,  4],
       [ 4, 14,  0,  4],
       [ 4, 14,  3,  3],
       [ 4, 14,  5,  8],
       [ 4, 14,  6,  8],
       [ 4, 14,  7,  8],
       [ 4, 14,  8,  8],
       [ 5, 13,  1,  3],
       [ 7, 11,  0,  2],
       [ 7, 11,  3,  0],
       [ 9,  9,  0,  0]])

In [169]: weights[1]*a[3] + weights[17]*b[5]
Out[169]: 0.60000000000000009

In [170]: weights[3]*a[2] + weights[15]*b[4]
Out[170]: 0.60000000000000009

In [171]: weights[1] + weights[17]
Out[171]: 1.0000000000000002

In [172]: weights[3] + weights[15]
Out[172]: 1.0
```

Comment: One question, why is the last column in idx for both a and b? Apologies if this is a misunderstanding due to my lack of clarity/knowledge, but any combination of a and b would works as long as the result is x..

Comment: @cJc Well my idea is that only for a specific combination of weights from `weights` and specific `a` and the corresponding  value from `b`, we would get `w * a + y * b = x`. Or did you mean by we need to take combinations from `a` and `b` separately too? Can you give us one sample combination of weights and `a` and `b` that would satisfy both those conditions?

Comment: @cJc Also, in your code, you have : `w * a + y * b`. Now `w` is a scalar, whereas `a` and `b` are 1D arrays. Thus, `w * a + y * b` would a 1D array. Then, you are equating it against `x` which is a scalar. What is that equating supposed to  signify?

Comment: Then my code is wrong, sorry. What I ment was any weighted combination of a and b, with varying weights totalling 1, that equals x.

Comment: @cJc As I said, `weighted combination of a and b` when taking all elements of `a` and `b` would give you a 1D array, which you can't equate to a scalar `x`, unless you mean taking one element each from `a` and `b` at a time.

Comment: In the above example we have a = [ 1.2,  1.3,  1.4,  1.5,  1.6,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ] and b = [ 0. ,  0.1,  0.2,  0.3,  0.4,  0.5,  0.6,  0.7,  0.8]. If I understand you correctly varying weights are assigned to a and b in sequence? I.e. same position [0,1,2...,8] for both a and b? What I ment is doing the same for a[0] vs b[0...8], a[1] vs b[0...8] and so forth, with varying weights. Is this not possible?

Comment: @cJc And by varying weights, do you mean different combinations of weights for `a` and different  for `b` i.e. (1) weight[0]*a[0] vs weight[0]*b[0...8] and then weight[**0**]*a[0] vs weight[1]*b[0...8] or (2) weight[0]*a[0] vs weight[0]*b[0...8] and then weight[**1**]*a[0] vs weight[1]*b[0...8] , if you see the pattern there?

Comment: Alternative (1) is exactly what I mean.

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks a lot for your efforts!